# Lotus Notes client setting for pasting plain text

Tags: lotus-notes

It is so much annoying to always think about when pasting text (or even one word) from a Website into a Notes mail by doing it with ctrl+shift+v iso to do it with ctrl+v like in every other application!

Because if you do it the common way ctrl+v Notes Client crashes or takes minutes (really minutes !!!) to paste the text into a mail.

It seems that even Notes 9 cannot handle formatted text from a Website but only plain text properly.

So my question: is there any Setting I can do to Change this to ctrl+v  iso ctrl+shift+v ??

Mostly all users in a worldwide corporation "suffer" from Notes (not only because of this issue) and I would appreciate any solution.
BTW: yes, I know, the solution would be to throw overboard Notes, but unfortunately the Management does not listen.
Michael

Comment: If you select formatted text on a webpage and paste it into Word using Ctrl-V, you get the formatted text.
If you select formatted text on a webpage and paste it into Notes using Ctrl-V, you get the formatted text.

Consistent between the two programs.

If you want to paste without formatting (plain text) into Notes you can use Shift-Ctrl-V in Notes (or Paste Special and select "Text").
To do the same in Word you have to right-click and select the last icon to the right under Paste in the menu...

Comment: I never had Notes (v7, v8 or v9) crash on me when I paste in formatted text from a webpage. In most cases when people complain about Notes it is one or both of the following reasons:
1) No training, either not provided by the company or ignored by the user
2) Bad setup/configuration of the client and/or servers by the admin/IT staff.
If you look in the LinkedIn forums or in some Facebook groups you get scared when you see how little some admins actually know. Especially the ones from India... If you had one of them setup the system, don't blame the product.

Comment: In addition to Karl-Henrys comment: In Word pasting with Ctrl + V will last as long as pasting in Word (and same is true for Outlook): This is an Internet Explorer Problem / Proxy- Problem, NOT a Lotus Notes Problem.

Comment: @Thorsten (aha es ist Tode!)
If seems as you are right!!
I tried with Google crome and it worked, same with IE, Notes crashes !!
Do you know if there is a Setting in IE which does avoid this behaviour?
Thanks!